# CodeCogs Latex Editor not working

Tags: html, image, latex

So Codecogs latex editor and interpreter has been crashing a lot over the past month or two. I have emailed their customer support several times with no reply and their forum has been down for weeks. Many days their whole website is down. I have a math website and many of my images and links for tests no longer work because their servers are down. I have over 5000 questions with links to codecogs and I am trying to find another website interpreter that can read those images. Does anyone know what is going on with codecogs? Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get around this problem?

Comment: See [Compiling documents online](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3/5764). There are many full-fledged online compilers, but also some equation editors only online compilers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about support for an external service and does not directly ask about anything programming related.

Answer (score 1):

Since a few people seemed to be having the same issue, I thought I would share a fix since codecogs website has now been down for several days. It's not pretty but it works and if you have thousands of images and can not manually go in a change each image, this has been the best solution I could find.

Mathjax is a great online latex interpreter and the only one I could find that was able to get the job done.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}
    });
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?      config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('img').each(function(){
       var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
       var src = $(this).attr('src');
       if(src.substring(0,11) == "http://late"){
        alt = alt.replace("inline", "");    //inline latex markup is not supported by mathjax
        var newAlt = "$"+alt+"$";
        $(this).replaceWith(newAlt);
    }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).